# Android: In-Call Volume Mute

Tags: java, android

I would like to know if there's any way to completely mute the android In-Call volume. Using the codes below, I managed to get it to be very low, but not completely mute. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 0, 0);
```

I'm using API 26 and the most recent version of Android Studio.

Thanks!